# Calculating the integral of two normal CDFs with a normal distribution

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate: $$\int\Phi((x-\mu_{1})/\sigma_{1})*\Phi((x-\mu_{2})/\sigma_{2})*\phi(x)dx$$ where $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are the standard normal cumulative distribution function and probability density function, respectively.

The reason I'm trying to do this is that I want to use truncated variational posteriors in a variational inference model and I need to find out the normalizing constant for the combination of a normal with a differential approximation of a step function.

There is some stuff calculating $E[\Phi((x-b)/a)]$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101469/integration-of-the-product-of-pdf-cdf-of-normal-distribution) on Math Overflow.  However, I need two truncation terms and not just one.  I can't think how to extend the proof given in the link to two normal CDFs.  I've tried writing $N(\mu,\sigma)$ as $\mu + \sigma*N(0,1)$ for the CDFs and doing u substitution but that seems to not work (I get infinities usually).  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you really mean $\Phi((x - \mu_1) / \sigma_1) \Phi((x - \mu_1) / \sigma_1)$, or should it be $\Phi((x - \mu_1) / \sigma_1) \Phi((x - \mu_2) / \sigma_2)$?

Comment: Assuming you meant exactly what you wrote, you might find the techniques at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61080 useful.  Otherwise, if @Dougal's suspicion is correct, you will need to integrate numerically.

Answer (score 6):

This integral:
$$
\int_\mathbf{R} \Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)
\phi(x)
\, \mathrm dx
$$
can be expressed like this:
[image]

where $T$ is the Owen $T$-function and $\textrm{BvN}$ is the bivariate normal distribution function.

*Source:* Owen, A table of normal integrals, 1980.

Check:

```
> integrand <- function(x, a, b, c, d){
+   pnorm(a+b*x)*pnorm(c+d*x)*dnorm(x)
+ }
> a <- 1; b <- 2; c <- 3; d <- 4
> integrate(integrand, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)
0.6404609 with absolute error < 4.7e-05
> 
> rho <- b*d/(sqrt(1+b^2)*sqrt(1+d^2))
> Sigma <- matrix(c(1,rho,rho,1), ncol=2)
> mvtnorm::pmvnorm(upper=c(a/sqrt(1+b^2), c/sqrt(1+d^2)), sigma = Sigma)
[1] 0.6404609
attr(,"error")
[1] 1e-15
attr(,"msg")
[1] "Normal Completion"
> 
> library(OwenQ)
> pnorm(a/sqrt(1+b^2))/2 + pnorm(c/sqrt(1+d^2))/2 -
+   OwenT(a/sqrt(1+b^2), (c+c*b^2-a*b*d)/a/sqrt(1+b^2+d^2)) -
+   OwenT(c/sqrt(1+d^2), (a+a*d^2-b*c*d)/c/sqrt(1+b^2+d^2))
[1] 0.6404609
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of the integral can be interpreted as the probability that a standard normal random variable $X$ is larger than $\max(Y,Z)$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are independent $N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$
random variables. Note that
$$P\{Y < X, Z < X\mid X = x\} = \Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)$$
by independence and the law of total probability then tells us that
\begin{align}
P\{X > \max(Y,Z)\} &= \int_\mathbf{R}P\{Y < X, Z < X\mid X = x\} \phi(x)
\, \mathrm dx\\
&= \int_\mathbf{R} \Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)
\phi(x)
\, \mathrm dx 
\end{align}
which, as whuber's comment points out, has no known analytical solution
in simple terms. Numerical integration is necessary except in some special cases (e.g. the answers to [this recent question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/291389/6633) or 
[this earlier one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/43685/6633)).